# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement springpython==1.2.1.FINAL

Tags: python, pip

I'm suddenly getting this error when I try to run `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement springpython==1.2.1.FINAL (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (from versions: 1.3.0rc1)
No distributions matching the version for springpython==1.2.1.FINAL (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
```

Here's my requirements.txt file:

```
--allow-all-external
--allow-unverified springpython
boto==2.38.0
demjson==2.2.2
Django==1.8.6
django-storages==1.1.8
django-extensions==1.5.9
newrelic==2.58.2.45
pytz==2015.07
six==1.9.0
springpython==1.2.1.FINAL
ujson==1.33
yappi==0.92
greenlet==0.4.9
gevent==1.1rc1
geventhttpclient==1.2.0
python-magic==0.4.10
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Who generated the `requirements.txt`, and how? The only version of `springpython` [available on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/springpython) is 1.3.0.RC1, so the requirement can't be met.

Comment: I did, manually. I added the `springpython` line 11 months ago, and have never had a problem until today.

Comment: Well the PyPI repo apparently hasn't changed since mid-2013, so I don't know what to tell you!

Comment: Weird. There is still a [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/springpython/1.2.1.FINAL) for 1.2.1.FINAL, but it doesn't have a green download button or file link.

Comment: I suggest you raise this with the package maintainers to find out if they've changed something, there's not much we can do for you here.